# How to load the rspec fixtures in to the database from the files

Tags: rspec, ruby-on-rails-5, rspec-rails, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I am using rails 5 with ruby 2.4 and gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.8' 
I am using 'devise' gem for the user model the fixture for it is as:
fixture: users.yml

```
# Read about fixtures at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FixtureSet.html

one:
  first_name: one
  last_name: Hotmail
  email: vidur.punj@gmail.com
#  password: 123greetings
  encrypted_password: <%= User.new.send(:password_digest, '123greetings') %>
  confirmed_at: <%= DateTime.now %>
  created_at: 2018-11-26 14:16:12
  updated_at: 2018-11-26 14:16:12

two:
  first_name: one
  last_name: Gmail
  email: vidur.punj@hotmail.com
#  password: 123greetings
  encrypted_password: <%= User.new.send(:password_digest, '123greetings') %>
  confirmed_at: <%= DateTime.now %>
  created_at: 2018-11-26 14:16:12
  updated_at: 2018-11-26 14:16:12
```

But I am not able to persist this data into the database via command line.
Yes the data get persisted when write

```
fixtures :users
```

inside my controller,
But how to persist at boot time of the project string in test mode. 
and data should refresh on restarting the server in test mode.
thanks in advance

Comment: rake db:fixtures:load RAILS_ENV=test FIXTURES_PATH=spec/fixtures

Comment: Ruby 4? Ruby 3 isn't out yet.

Comment: ruby 2.4 and rails 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For database fixtures being available before the application boots, you need to execute this rake task:

```
RAILS_ENV=test FIXTURES_PATH="spec/fixtures" rails db:fixtures:load
```